# Distance to object (from focal information)

Tags: geometry

How would one compute the distance to the observed object from a JPEG file (picture taken by camera).

**jhead** usually reveals something like:

```
File name    : foo.jpg
Resolution   : 1600 x 1200
Flash used   : No
Focal length :  5.4mm  (35mm equivalent: 36mm)
CCD Width    : 5.23mm
Exposure time: 0.100 s  (1/10)
Aperture     : f/2.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need more data, which would usually be the actual size of some object in the picture and how large it is on the sensor.  Otherwise the object can be twice as large and twice as far away and generate the same image.  The only useful information you got from jhead is the focal length of the lens.  Assuming the object is far away compared to 5.4mm, the relation is (size of object)/(distance to object)=(size of image)/5.4mm.  To use this you need to know the size of your sensor, which is indicated by the ratio $\frac {36}{5.4}\approx 6.667$ which doesn't match any of the standard formats in [the Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor_format).  Alternately, you can print it making the frame $1 \times 1.5$ inches and use (size of object)/(distance to object)=(size of image)/36 mm from that, counting on the 35mm equivalence of the lens.